# Cloning Kia Picanto key with Zed Bull Programmer

Tags: kia, locks, key, picanto

Not so long ago I bought a second hand Kia Picanto, but unlikely it came with only one key.
Cloning this kind of key seemed pretty expensive, so I did a small research about key cloning, since cloning key without also cloning its transponder could result with engine locking.
I've learned that there are devices that allow you to write to key transponder, and that the price can range around 500$, but there are also cheep transponder programmer tools that cost around 25$, for example Zed Bull.

I would like to hear some opinions about key cloning with this cheep devices, before I order it and get my hands on cloning. I wounder if Zed Bull (https://www.hickleys.com/diagnostics/zedbull.php) is really capable of cloning Kia Picanto key without risk that engine is going to end up locked. That could actually save me from paying key cloning that is basically two times the price of this device.

Answer (score 1):

The Zed Bull is a lot more than $500 let alone $25. You're going to need to be cloning a great many keys to make one pay for itself! Additionally (as SolarMike's answer states) there are potential pitfalls to cloned keys (as opposed to additional keys correctly paired to the car) - and although not the most likely thing why take the risk?

Even for cars such as the Picanto where the pairing process is supposed to be dealer only (i.e. there isn't a user procedure to do it) auto locksmiths generally have the tools needed to pair a new key so you just give them the blank and let them do the rest.

Comment: I doubt that i will take any risk, but it is important to learn about things and understand them. Sooner or later any kind of knowladge may pay off. Imagine if i could do cloning of keys of some other cars (with minimum risk), then i could even make some profit of it, right?

Comment: @adict learning new skills and knowledge is definitely a good thing - it's just that in 99/100 scenarios you're going to be better off putting that effort into knowing how to properly pair keys then cloning